# html,js:populate form fields with values from arraylist and save back this arraylist in servlet

Tags: javascript, java

I have an html form with textboxes and below that is a dynamically created table with an edit and delete hyperlink. When I click the edit link, the values corresponding to that row have to get populated in the corresponding textboxes so that the user can edit them. Below is the code for table generation:

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${memberList}">
   <input type="hidden" name="chk" id="chk" value="${row.connectionName}" />
    <tr>

        <td><c:out value="${row.connectionName}"/> </td>
        <td><c:out value="${row.desc}"></c:out> </td>

        <td><a href="#" name="EditConn" id="EditConn">Edit</a><td>
        <td><a href="#" name="Delete" id="Delete">Delete</a> </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Sending `memberList` from servlet as `request.setAttribute("memberList",memberList);`.

I get the table values populated correctly. Now, in order to get values corresponding to a particular row (on edit click event) into their corresponding textboxes in the form, what can be done?

P.S. I tried using a hidden field near the edit link

```
    <td><a href="#" name="EditConn" id="EditConn" 
    onclick="fnGetName();">Edit</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="connFromList" id="connFromList" 
    value="${row.connectionName}" /><td>
```

and tried to alert the `connFromList` value, but it was always giving me the first row value. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are setting the id to each row with the same value. The best way to do it, it's passing the value of row.connectionName as a parameter on your function. It could be:

```
<td>
    <a href="#" name="EditConn" id="${row.connectionName}"
       onclick="fnGetName(this.id);">
        Edit
    </a>
<td>
```

and from the javascript side, the function should receive a parameter and should looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fnGetName(clickedId){
        alert(clickedId);
    }
</script>
```

Hope it helps.